# How to find PolicyNumber that have more than one DIFFERENT SICCode from the same source table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, having

I have table with `PolicyNumber` and `SICCode`.

[image]

Typically each `PolicyNumber` has only one unique `SICCode`. But I want to check, to make sure the data is correct. 
How would I do that?

The query below gives me the number of `SICCode`'s each `PolicyNumber` has, but its not what I need.  I want to identify what `PolicyNumber` (if any) has more than one DIFFERENT `SICCodes`.

```
select  PolicyNumber, 
        count(SICCode) as count  
from    PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet 
group by PolicyNumber 
having count(SICCode)>1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT SICCode)`:

```
Select  PolicyNumber,
        Count(Distinct SICCode) As count
From    PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
Group By PolicyNumber
Having  Count(Distinct SICCode) > 1;
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you very much #Siyual